# Is this a bug? NullPointerException when trying to generate from s/or spec which includes nil

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, clojure.spec

I found a way to throw NullPointerExceptions by generating values using an `s/or` spec. I want to be able to generate and label a `nil` value, no `s/nilable` isn't suitable.

Is this a bug in `clojure.spec`?

```clj
(ns blah
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s])) 

(s/def ::fine (s/or :int int? :nil nil?)
(s/def ::throws (s/or :int (s/int-in 1 5) :zero zero? :nil nil?)

(s/exercise ::fine)
=>
([nil [:nil nil]
 [-1 [:int -1]]
 [nil [:nil nil]]
 [0 [:int 0]]
 [nil [:nil nil]]
 [15 [:int 15]]
 [-25 [:int -25]]
 [nil [:nil nil]]
 [-2 [:int -2]]
 [-30 [:int -30]]])]])

(s/exercise ::throws)
=>
NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Numbers.ops (Numbers.java:1018)
```

If you limit the number of times `::throws` is exercised, you see correct `:int` and `:zero` values, it's the `:nil` which throws.

Comment: `(zero? nil)` throws npe. I was able to get it working with `:zero (s/int-in 0 1)` but it would still be interesting to know why the problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
(s/def ::works (s/or :int (s/int-in 1 5) :nil nil? :zero zero?))
```

I assume spec will try to conform in order of the `or` alternatives. Conforming `nil` using the `zero?` predicate will crash, but moving `nil?` in front of that, will prevent that from happening.

What also works is using a set instead of a predicate:

```
(s/def ::throws (s/or :int (s/int-in 1 5) :zero #{0} :nil nil?))
```

Comment: Oops forgot to test that order, thanks! Should I try to submit a patch to the docstring?

Comment: Using a set predicate `:zero #{0}` instead of `:zero zero?` also works. I agree it throws because `zero?` is called with a (valid) nil input during conform. Same as `(s/conform zero? nil)`.

Comment: Thanks Taylor, used #{0} now in the last part.

Comment: @JeremyField I think the thing to highlight here is that not all predicates are equally suited for spec. `zero?`, like `odd?` and `even?`, is one of those predicates expecting valid number input (probably for performance reasons), and needs an additional `int?` check to be safe for use in spec. This is in contrast with predicates that can handle input of _any_ type, like `nil?` or `int?` or `simple-keyword?`.